# one Jackson deserializer for multiple types (config by annotation)

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to change the (de)serialization of a list in one of my classes.

the objects in the list shall be serialised as int (their jpa id) and deserialised accordingly. serialization is simple.

for the deserialization i have a class that can translate the id into the object if id and class are known.

How do i get the necessary class from jackson? all default jackson serialisers have a constructor like this: `protected StdDeserialiser(Class<?> vc)` so the information is present somewhere.

is there a way to access it during deserialisation?
or before the deserialiser is constructed by jackson?
or inside the HandlerInstantiator?

I only want to overwrite the default deseriliser for certain references so i can't just write a provider or a custom module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work from inside the deserializer with the help of the ContextDeserializer interface as this supplies the deserializer with the target property.

```
public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
    Class<?> vc = null;
    if (property.getType().isCollectionLikeType()) {
        vc = property.getType().getContentType().getRawClass();
    } else {
        vc = property.getType().getRawClass();
    }
    return new ResourcePathDeserializer(vc, converter);
}
```

This solution is not perfect as I only get the raw class of the return type or the generic (which might be a parent class or an interface) but that is enough for my requirements.
It would be better if I could access the "real" class that was resolved by Jackson, but for me this works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is nothing fancy about writing a Module: it is just a way for plugging things in, like custom (de)serializers. So no need to avoid that. And you will most like need to write a module to do what you want.

In general it is not a good idea to try to create "universal" serializers or deserializers, and it will probably run into problem. But it depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

Type information will either be:

- Implicit from context: you are writing a (de)serializer for type T, and register it for it, so that's your type
- Passed by Jackson when (de)serializer is being constructed, via `Module` interface: modules are asked if they happen to have a (de)serializer for type T. `SimpleModule` will only use basic Class-to-impl mapping (that's where "simple" comes from); but full custom `Module` has access to incoming type.

But I don't know if above will work for your use case. Type information must be available from static type (declared content type for the list).